# The Patent For " Molded Sports Board" Patent # EP1745909 A2

Tags: ep1745909a2, molded, sports, board

My question is for the Molded sports board by Inventor  Wah Kan Cheung (Kenneth) I simply want to manufacture a Snow Sled such as one on this Image page:   https://www.google.com/search?q=foam+snow+sleds&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=_Mh1UuepNuO8iwLtyoGQBA&sqi=2&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1280&bih=832    Does the Above patent cover these simple Foam sleds?    Do all these companies have to pay Inventor Wah Kan Cheung to license his patent when they make a foam sled or do I have a completely wrong patent?   This Patent is the only one I could find involving a simple foam sled.   Thank you.